# renewing the value of variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello everyone on stack

I've been stuck with this problem for hours and I am desperate for help

here's my code

```
def function(seq):
    ascending_list = list(sorted(seq, key=int))

    for i in range(0, len(ascending_list) - 1, 2):
        ascending_list[i], ascending_list[i + 1] = ascending_list[i + 1], ascending_list[i]
    seq = ascending_list


>>> seq = [11, 91, 50, 3, 2, 6, 24]
>>> function(seq)
>>> seq
```

in the end, when 'seq' is inputted into console
i want the modified list of integers, [3, 2, 11, 6, 50, 24, 91], to be outputted.
Problem here is that the program keeps on outputting the original list, which is [11, 91, 50, 3, 2, 6, 24]

my code works perfectly fine when I perform

```
def function(seq):
    ascending_list = list(sorted(seq, key=int))

    for i in range(0, len(ascending_list) - 1, 2):
        ascending_list[i], ascending_list[i + 1] = ascending_list[i + 1], ascending_list[i]
    return ascending_list

>>> seq = [11, 91, 50, 3, 2, 6, 24]
>>> function(seq)
[3, 2, 11, 6, 50, 24, 91]
```

but how can assign this new list as 'seq', so that when 'seq' is typed into the console it would output [3, 2, 11, 6, 50, 24, 91]

Comment: better don't change the list, but assign the returned list to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign to a slice instead of assigning to `seq`:

```
def function(seq):
    ascending_list = list(sorted(seq, key=int))

    for i in range(0, len(ascending_list) - 1, 2):
        ascending_list[i], ascending_list[i + 1] = ascending_list[i + 1], ascending_list[i]
    seq[:] = ascending_list


seq = [11, 91, 50, 3, 2, 6, 24]
function(seq)
seq
# [3, 2, 11, 6, 50, 24, 91]
```

If you have `seq = ...` in your function, `seq` will be considered a local variable that will just be discarded when the function returns. If we assign to a slice of `seq`, we update the one you passed as parameter in-place.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the return value to a variable:

```
def function(seq):
    ascending_list = list(seq)
    ascending_list.sort(key=int)
    end = -(len(ascending_list)&1) or None
    ascending_list[:end:2], ascending_list[1::2] = ascending_list[1::2], ascending_list[:end:2]
    return ascending_list

>>> seq = [11, 91, 50, 3, 2, 6, 24]
>>> seq = function(seq)
>>> seq
[3, 2, 11, 6, 50, 24, 91]
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is return `ascending_list` from `function`:

```
def function(seq):
    ascending_list = list(sorted(seq, key=int))

    for i in range(0, len(ascending_list) - 1, 2):
        ascending_list[i], ascending_list[i + 1] = ascending_list[i + 1], ascending_list[i]
    return ascending_list


seq = [11, 91, 50, 3, 2, 6, 24]
seq = function(seq)
```

This would be the cleanest way, because it means `function` doesn't have any side-effects.

You could also have `function` modify `seq` in-place:

```
def function(seq):
    # Note that we can call a method instead of sorted().
    seq.sort()

    for i in range(0, len(seq) - 1, 2):
        seq[i], seq[i + 1] = seq[i + 1], seq[i]


seq = [11, 91, 50, 3, 2, 6, 24]
function(seq)
```